# Why is JS in string concatenation inside of insertAdjacentHTML not being evaluated in rare circumstances?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line of JavaScript running on a public website that I don't own, essentially writing a magic pixel image to the page in order to call an API I provided (n is a reference to a DIV tag that I added to the page previously; line breaks added for readability, not in original code):

```
n.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
                     '<img src="https://myapiserver/api/SessionError?cust=ABCD&loc='  
                     + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)  
                     + '&ua='
                     + encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent.slice(0,255))  
                     + '" style="height:0px;width:0px">');
```

This code runs correctly most of the time, calling my API with the correct parameters. However, in my API log I found one instance (so far) where it was called with these parameter values:

- cust=ABCD
- loc=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + '
- ua=' + encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent.slice(0,255)) + '

This is the only line of code anywhere where this API is being called, so I know it was this line of code that produced this result.

Obviously, for the API to be called at all, JavaScript must have been executing in the browser, but for some reason the string concatenation wasn't evaluated correctly in this one situation. What could cause this behavior? Do I need to switch my quotes around for compatibility with certain browsers or locales?

Answer (score -1):

This was most likely a scraper bot that just matched your HTML with a regex expression and made a request to anything that looked like a URL, without actually evaluating any of your HTML nor JavaScript.

Comment: Wow, that didn't even cross my mind, but it sounds right. Thanks for the reassurance that I wasn't missing anything in my code.